# how can I execute "ffmpeg -video_size 1024x768 -framerate 25 -f x11grab -i :0.0+100,200 output.mp4" command in nodejs

Tags: node.js, video, ffmpeg

As I am new to Node and started working on cross platform desktop application using NWjs please assist me how to execute "ffmpeg -video_size 1024x768 -framerate 25 -f x11grab -i :0.0+100,200 output.mp4" command in nodejs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might want to look at the [child_process module](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) which is included in nodejs by default.

Here's a code example from the documentation using ls to list files in a directory:

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const ls = spawn('ls', ['-lh', '/usr']);

ls.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});

ls.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
});

ls.on('close', (code) => {
  console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
});
```